# Convergence in probability, continuity and uniform convergence in probability

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, time-series, law-of-large-numbers, stationary-processes

Let $(X_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a strictly stationary sequences of real valued random variables with finite variance. We have the empirical distribution functions $F_{n}(u):=\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n 1\{X_i\leq u\}$ and a continuous distribution function $F$. Assume that for all $u\in\mathbb{R}$
\begin{align*}
|F_{n}(u)-F(u)|\xrightarrow{p} 0
\end{align*}in probability for $n\rightarrow\infty$.
Holds now that
\begin{align*}
\sup_{u\in\mathbb{R}} |F_{n}(u)-F(u)|\xrightarrow{p} 0?
\end{align*}
Thanks!

Comment: The answer is yes if $(X_i,i\in\Bbb N)$ is ergodic. It's a result from Dehling and Philipp, 2002.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use Corollary 1.4 of paper

Ramon van Handel, *The universal Glivenko-Cantelli property*, Probab. Th. Rel. Fields 155, 911-934 (2013)

which is available [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1009.4434) (especially point 8).  The assumption about pointwise convergence allows us to see that for all $u$,
$$F(u)=\mathbb P(\chi_{\{Z_0\leqslant u\}}\mid\mathcal I)\quad\mbox{p.s}.$$